# CKEDITOR - turn off html encoding

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

In my CKEDITOR, when I type following letters:

```
ó " ... whitespace and more
```

I am getting the following HTML:

```
&oacute; &bdquo; &hellip; &nbsp; and so on...
```

How can I turn this off, so that the server will receive "normal" letters?

Comment: You should fix your server to accept valid HTML.  How do you handle `&`?

Comment: @SLaks: My server handles it without a problem. I just don't want CKEDITOR to convert normal letters into encoded values.

Comment: Make sure your page encoding is UTF-8.  Otherwise you'll get meta-characters inserted because ordinary encoding can't handle ASCII values beyond 127.  CKEDITOR may still not do it correctly, but at least you'll have the page encoding correct.

Answer (score 22):

I managed to reduce the number of characters converted by adding this to my config file:

```
config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;
config.entities = false;
```

But whitespaces are still being converted into `&nbsp;`...

Comment: For spaces you want: config.basicEntities = false;
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-basicEntities

Comment: @PeterValadez it still doesn't work, I get `&amp;` inside `<a href="bla&bla" />`

Comment: That's exactly what you want to happen @Mr.TA. A simple `&` is invalid in raw HTML.

Comment: @bradlis7 are you sure? With `&amp;` in the href, the link doesn't work (because the query string can't get parsed correctly).

Comment: @Mr.TA It's HTML encoded. Just as you'd expect `<span>A &amp; B</span>` to output 'A & B', if you put `&amp;` inside of the `href` attribute, the browser interprets it as `&`.

Comment: @bradlis7 you are right, it was an unrelated bug in another component.