# After using CKeditor tools getting HTML Tags on emails

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to send an email which is working but the message I am getting with HTML tags like I wrote `"Hello everyone! How are you guys"` with help of editor I did in the bold text and sent the mail.

But I got a mail like `<strong>Hello</strong><strong> everyone! How are you guys</strong>`.

I tried `CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false;` it will work unless you haven't use the CKE tool bar but if we use the editor to change the text then getting HTML tags on mail.

Is there any option to display only text in the mail?

Check below link I am getting like this output in email after using CKEditor tools
http://prntscr.com/g0tzaa
PHP code I am getting string here in process and sending to mail

**HTMl**

```
<textarea name="mailbody" id="editor1" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

**editor script**

```
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
 CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false;
```

**PHP code**

```
$mailbody=$_POST['mailbody'];
```

**PHP mailing code**

```
function send($email,$subject, $mailbody){
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = 'mail.domain.com';
    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail->Port = 587;
    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
    $mail->Username = "ab@domain.com";
    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = "Pass#@123";
    $mail->setFrom('ab@domain.com', '');
    //Set the subject line
    $mail->addAddress=$email;//just for example
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body =$mailbody;
```

}

Comment: The data has probably saved the HTML tags urlencoded. Duplicate from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645750/ckeditor-turn-off-html-encoding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CKEDITOR - turn off html encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645750/ckeditor-turn-off-html-encoding)

Comment: Mr.Pokeybit. Where is the solution?

Comment: I am talking about after using CKEditor tool then I am getting HTML tags. and I tried that solution which is not working

Comment: My Question is different..If you know the solution then tell me

Comment: I have a solution but it is specific to PHP. What language are you using to create/send the email?

Comment: I am using PHP but I am using CKEditor

Comment: did you try my answer ? and also please provide more info like how you are reading data from ck editor to php and how you are sending that data to the mail method etc most probably its because of `content-type`

Comment: I just miss the $mail->isHTML(true); in my PHP mailer. Thanks, MR. Arun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your mail receives the message as text you need to send the message as html 
set content-type in your `sendmail` method

`"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"`

i dont know what language you are using to send mail i could give proper coding if i have more details thank you

**EDIT:**

Missing :

```
 `$mail->isHTML(true);`
```

My general Mail Method :

```
    public function send_mail($to, $subject, $body, $from = NULL, $from_name = NULL, $attachment = NULL, $cc = NULL, $bcc = NULL) {

        try {
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->isSMTP();
//             $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
            $mail->Host = $this->Settings->smtp_host;
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = $this->Settings->smtp_user;
            $mail->Password = $this->Settings->smtp_pass;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = !empty($this->Settings->smtp_crypto) ? $this->Settings->smtp_crypto : false;
            $mail->Port = $this->Settings->smtp_port;

            if ($from && $from_name) {
                $mail->setFrom($from, $from_name);
                $mail->setaddReplyToFrom($from, $from_name);
            } elseif ($from) {
                $mail->setFrom($from, $this->Settings->site_name);
                $mail->addReplyTo($from, $this->Settings->site_name);
            } else {
                $mail->setFrom($this->Settings->default_email, $this->Settings->site_name);
                $mail->addReplyTo($this->Settings->default_email, $this->Settings->site_name);
            }

            $mail->addAddress($to);
            if ($cc) { $mail->addCC($cc); }
            if ($bcc) { $mail->addBCC($bcc); }
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->isHTML(true);   //need to set this true for html emails 
            $mail->Body = $body;
            if ($attachment) {
                if (is_array($attachment)) {
                    foreach ($attachment as $attach) {
                        $mail->addAttachment($attach);
                    }
                } else {
                    $mail->addAttachment($attachment);
                }
            }

            if (!$mail->send()) {
                throw new Exception($mail->ErrorInfo);
                return FALSE;
            }
            return TRUE;
        } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->errorMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Arun, I am still getting the issue. I am using CKEditor If I write any think and change the text from normal to Bold with the help of CKEditor tools then I am getting HTML tags

Comment: try you method manually with message `<strong>Hello</strong><strong> everyone! How are you guys</strong>` and check you are getting bold text or tags

Comment: I update my description with a link. Please check it

Comment: share  your `$mailbody` content and your mail method please

Comment: Yes, Mr.Arun I updated my code in description Please check it.

Comment: Oh, My God. Finally I got my solution. $mail->isHTML(true); is missing in PHP mailer. I am struggling this from last 4-5 days. Big Thank you,  Mr. Arun. Upvote from My side.

Comment: glad to know it fixed :D

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the mail program you are using. I use PEAR Mail_Mime and basically with `$body_html` coming from the output of CKeditor

```
$mime = new Mail_mime("\n");
$body_txt = strip_tags($body_html);
$mime->setHTMLBody($body_html);
$mime->setTXTBody($body_txt . "\n\n");
```

plus some additional code to set From/To/Subject headers, etc.

A typical email will have both a plain text component and an HTML component. The plain text is used in some cases for preview and in some older text-only clients. The vast majority of modern email clients display the HTML if available. `strip_tags` simply removes all the HTML tags for the plain text version.

If the email program you use is extremely simple then it won't have the mime format and by default definition of internet email it will treat the text as plain text. If that's the case then just use strip_tags to clean it up, though you may want to add a `str_replace` to change some of the tags first to \n or \r\n in order to have line breaks in the email text.

Comment: MR.Manassehkatz, This is my user Interface link http://prntscr.com/g0u26v

Comment: What I am doing is I am entering the email and subject and adding the body content and editing the text with CKEditor to look good and sending email with PHP mailer

Comment: Mr.Manassehkatz I don't know how to use pear mail

Comment: @NarendraVerma OK. I see now you posted the full code - and with that the answer was relatively easy (and already done by @ArunpandianM). In the future, post as much relevant code as possible at the beginning and you'll get a faster answer.