# CKEDITOR : Convert ALT+NUM to entity automatically remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

Whenever I typed inside CKEDITOR `Alt+0151` then it will be converted like this `__(n-dash)`.

I want to know which plugin do this ?  and

How can I Stop this Functionality?

Comment: maybe duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645750/ckeditor-turn-off-html-encoding

Comment: No, it's not like that. I think that is different.

Comment: Press ALT and Press 0151 then see the majik.